# Hydrogen 2p3/2 -> 1s1/2 transition polarisation and angular distribution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, atomic-physics, hydrogen

Could you please help me. I have to calculate the intensity angular and polarisation  distribution in hydrogen electric dipole transition $\text{2p}_{3/2}\rightarrow \text{1s}_{1/2}$. To do this I have to calculate the transition dipole moment $\langle \text{out}|q_e\hat{\vec{r}}|\text{in}\rangle $ But nothing is said about the quantum number $j_z = m_j$. Does it mean that I have 8 (3, in fact, but still not 1) problems for each transition 
$|n=2,l=1,j=3/2, m_j=\pm3/2\rangle \rightarrow |n=1,l=0,j=1/2, m_j=\pm1/2 \rangle $
$|n=2,l=1,j=3/2, m_j=\pm3/2\rangle \rightarrow |n=1,l=0,j=1/2, m_j=\mp1/2 \rangle $(forbidden)
$|n=2,l=1,j=3/2, m_j=\pm1/2\rangle \rightarrow |n=1,l=0,j=1/2, m_j=\pm1/2 \rangle $
$|n=2,l=1,j=3/2, m_j=\pm1/2\rangle \rightarrow |n=1,l=0,j=1/2, m_j=\mp1/2 \rangle $

Than I can write those wavefunctions through general hydrogen wavefunctions and spin part using Clebsch–Gordan coefficients:

$\lvert l=1,j=3/2, m_j=3/2\rangle = \lvert l=1,m_l=1\rangle\lvert\uparrow\rangle$
$\lvert l=1,j=3/2, m_j=1/2\rangle = \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\lvert l=1,m_l=0\rangle\lvert\uparrow\rangle+ \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}\lvert l=1,m_l=1\rangle\lvert\downarrow\rangle$
$\lvert l=0,j=1/2, m_j=1/2 \rangle = \lvert l=0,m_l=0\rangle\lvert\uparrow\rangle $

analogues for $m_j<0$  with only change of $m_l$ and spin to contrary.

Then I can calculate transition dipole moments (charge dropped, any bra has $\langle n=2\rvert$, any ket - $\lvert n=1\rangle$):

$\langle  l=0,j=1/2, m_j=1/2\rvert \hat{\vec{r}}\lvert  l=1,j=3/2,m_j=3/2 \rangle=$
$=\langle l=0,m_l=0 \rvert \hat{\vec{r}} \lvert l=1,m_l=1 \rangle=$
$=\text{assuming the exact  configurational representation}= \frac{2^7}{3^5}a_0 \overrightarrow{\{1,i,0\}}=:\vec{a}$
$\langle  l=0,j=1/2, m_j=-1/2\rvert \hat{\vec{r}}\lvert  l=1,j=3/2,m_j=-3/2 \rangle=\vec{a}^{*}$
$\langle l=0,j=1/2, m_j=1/2 \rvert \hat{\vec{r}}\lvert  l=1,j=3/2,m_j=1/2\rangle=$
$= \left(\langle l=0,m_l=0\rvert\langle\uparrow\rvert\right) \hat{\vec{r}} \left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\lvert l=1,m_l=0\rangle\lvert\uparrow\rangle+ \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}\lvert l=1,m_l=1\rangle\lvert\downarrow\rangle \right) = 0$, what told me @Sofia, but I still do not clearly understand, why this is obvious.
$\langle l=0,j=1/2, m_j=-1/2 \rvert \hat{\vec{r}}\lvert  l=1,j=3/2,m_j=-1/2\rangle=0$ 
$\langle l=0,j=1/2, m_j=-1/2 \rvert \hat{\vec{r}}\lvert  l=1,j=3/2,m_j=1/2\rangle=$
$= \left(\langle l=0,m_l=0\rvert\langle\downarrow\rvert\right) \hat{\vec{r}} \left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\lvert l=1,m_l=0\rangle\lvert\uparrow\rangle+ \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}\lvert l=1,m_l=1\rangle\lvert\downarrow\rangle \right) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}\vec{a}$
$\langle l=0,j=1/2, m_j=1/2 \rvert \hat{\vec{r}}\lvert  l=1,j=3/2,m_j=-1/2\rangle=\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}\vec{a}^{*}$
$\langle l=0,j=1/2, m_j=-1/2 \rvert \hat{\vec{r}}\lvert l=1,j=3/2,m_j=3/2\rangle=$
$=\left(\langle l=0,m_l=0\rvert\langle\downarrow\rvert\right)\hat{\vec{r}}\left(\lvert l=1,m_l=1 \rangle\lvert\uparrow\rangle\right) =0$ (forbidden)
$\langle l=0,j=1/2, m_j=1/2 \rvert \hat{\vec{r}}\lvert l=1,j=3/2,m_j=-3/2\rangle=0$

So, I analysed all cases and now can write $I(p=\{L,R\}, \theta,\varphi)\propto \left|\vec{a} \vec{e}_p(\theta,\varphi)\right|^2$, were $\vec{e}_p(\theta,\varphi)$ is polarisation ort ( $\vec{e}_R(\theta,\varphi)=\{-\cos\theta \cos\varphi, -\cos\theta \sin\varphi, \sin\theta\},$
$ \vec{e}_L(\theta,\varphi)=\{\sin\varphi, -\cos\varphi, 0\}$). But doing this I will receive asymmetric distributions (there is dependency on $\theta$ and no symmetry $L\leftrightarrow R$):
$I(R,\theta,\varphi)=I_0\cos^2\theta,\text{  }I(L,\theta,\varphi)=I_0$
 that is strange as the problems looks totally symmetric.

Is it true, that we can't determin the intensity angular and polarisation  distribution in hydrogen for transition $\text{2p}_{3/2}\rightarrow \text{1s}_{1/2}$ in general? What will be observed in the experiment?

Comment: Unless I have forgotten something trivial about the hydrogen problem I can't see why one could not calculate the angular distribution and polarization. Is the symmetry broken by a magnetic field? I think so, so you may have to deal with that one by one. But since I have forgotten almost everything about spin-orbital angular momentum coupling, I have to pass on real help with the problem.

Comment: @Basil Some transitions that you mention are impossible: from +1/2 to +1/2 and from -1/2 to -1/2. The photon is considered as having angular momentum $+\hbar$ or $- \hbar$. There remain 4 possibilities. But I believe that there has to be symmetry between the cases $3/2 \to 1/2$ and $-3/2 \to -1/2 $. Also between $1/2 \to -1/2$ and $-1/2 \to 1/2$.

Comment: @Basil : so you have to calculate the angular intensity for only 2 cases. As to polarization, it is circular in all these cases. From bigger $m_z$ to lower you have right polarization, including the case $1/2 \to -1/2$, and from lower to bigger, left circular polarization, including the case from $-1/2 \to 1/2$.

Comment: @Sofia Thank you for answer. Sure, there is a symmetry in cases $3/2→1/2$ and $−3/2→−1/2$ and also between $1/2→−1/2$ and $−1/2→1/2$, I mean this by writing $\pm$. But I thought that transition with $\Delta m_j = 0$ is not forbidden and corresponds to linear polarization (please note, that $j$ is the total moment ($\hat{\vec{J}} = \hat{\vec{L}}+\hat{\vec{S}}$ )? 
I understand, that due to the symmetry $m_j$ shold not be important, but for some reason I need it in my calculations. Should it be given several answers depending on the transition? What will be observed in the experiment?

Comment: Probably, nothing is said about $m_z$ because no magnetic field is present.

Comment: @Basil: I just now see a mistake of notation. The quantum number $l$ may be at most equal to $n-1$, it can't be equal to $n$. Please look again at your question.

Comment: @Sofia Sure, it is a misprint, the should have been $l=1$ (**p**-state). Could you please give an answer to my previous comment? I think my problem is that I don't know how to build a wavefunction for state $|n=2,l=1,j=3/2 \rangle$ for calculating  $\langle \text{out}|q_e\hat{\vec{r}}|\text{in}\rangle $ wo knowing $m_j$

Comment: @About linear polarization, please see. The projection of the photon angular momentum on any axis, cannot be zero. The photon is very analogue with the fermion from this point of view. Even if you take a superposition like $|m_z = +1> +- |m_z = -1>$ you cannot get projection zero of the angular momentum on some axis.

Comment: @Basil : if there are several possible transitions, I am not sure. I see in fact 2 transitions (two angular distributions) because of the symmetry as I said.

Comment: @Sofia Thank you so much for your answers. In fact I stitt can't understand, why cant it happend so that the photon is linearly polarized and $\Delta j= \pm 1, \Delta m_j =0$? In many sourses (like [MIT lectures](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/chemistry/5-61-physical-chemistry-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT5_61F13_Lecture19-20.pdf), [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_rule)) this is considered as an ordinary situation... And in fact I am still  asking  myself about what will give us an experiment!

Comment: @Basil , I am answering you, please wait.

Comment: @Basil : consider a state of linear polarization, say x. What is the angular momentum of the photon in this state? For answering this question you have to decompose the state of linear polarization $|x>$ into a superposition of the two states of angular momentum projection of the photon: $|R>$ which corresponds to the projection $+\hbar$ on the direction of propagation of the photon, and $|L>$, which corresponds to the projection $-\hbar$ on the direction of propagation of the photon. These are its only two states of projection of angular momentum.

Comment: @Basil (continuation) The photon doesn't have a state of projection zero of its angular momentum. The construction of the photon is like this: its angular momentum is along the direction of propagation, and there are only two projections. So, a linear polarization, say, x, can be represented as $(|R> +- |L>)/ \sqrt (2)$. That means, in a linear polarization the photon has a probability 1/2 to be in the state $|R>$, i.e. angular momentum projection $\hbar$ and probability 1/2 to be in the state $|L>$, i.e. projection $-\hbar$.

Comment: @Basil : now, it's very late in my country, let's continue tomorrow. O.K. ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19787/discussion-between-basil-and-sofia).